# Replacing user selected text in Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Been googling this for a while and it seems really simple, but I can't work out the issue. I have a chrome extension where when you select some text, you right click and there is a button which will perform some maths on the selection. But for some reason, I can't get the selection to appear in an alert window.

```
if (window.getSelection) 
{
    window.alert("Does it enter if window.getselection");
    sel=window.getSelection();
    window.alert(sel);
}
```

So it enters the if statement, displays the first alert, then the second alert is blank. Losing my mind trying to work this out, it feels like it's going to be something so simple that I've missed. Also, what would be the best method of replacing the selected text? Thanks.

EDIT: You guys wanted to see my Manifest file.

```
{
"name": "Convert",
"description": "lorem",
"version": "0.6",
"permissions": ["contextMenus", "tabs", "windows"],
"background": {
"scripts": ["conversion.js"]
},
"manifest_version": 2
}
```

I'm guessing I've done something wrong here, I am a greenhorn when it comes to Chrome Extnesions.

Comment: Your problem most probably has to do with the context you call this from. Can you show more of your code, and where is it executed?

Comment: @Xan No problem, just put it up.

Answer (score 2):

You are a beginner at Chrome Extensions; therefore, take a look at the [Architecture Overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch).

If you read it, you will come back enlightened that background code runs in a separate page, and `window` refers to it and **not the currently open and visible tab**. To access that, you normally need some form of a [Content Script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts).

**But before you start implementing the content script**, let's have another look at the [context menu API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus).

The [handler of a context menu click event](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus#event-onClicked) receives an `info` object that, among other things, contains `selectionText` with the text selected at the moment of the invocation of the context menu. If that is all you want (and not the full `Selection` object), you don't need to interact with the page at all:

```
function handleContext(info){
  if(info.selectionText) {
    // There was something selected, do stuff with it
  }
}
```

If you DO need the full selection object, here's the minimal code for it (requires `activeTab` permission):

```
function handleContext(info, tab){
  if(tab){
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(
      tab.id,
      {code : "window.getSelection();"},
      function(results) {
        // Do something with results[0]
      }
    );
  }
}
```

See [Programmatic Injection](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#pi) and [`executeScript` docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript) for reference.

Answer (score -1):

You forgot the parenthesis. Try

```
if (window.getSelection()) 
{
    window.alert("Does it enter if window.getselection");
    sel=window.getSelection();
    window.alert(sel);
}
```

Because the function `getSelection` exists, `window.getSelection` is true, regardless of what `window.getSelection()` returns.

Comment: -1: `window.getSelection()` will return an object even if nothing is selected, ans will therefore be true.

Comment: @Xan So `window.getSelection()` and `window.getSelection` will always both return true, is that right ? That's good to know, thanks.

Comment: They won't return literal `true`: the first will return an `Object`, the other a `function`. Both, when converted to a boolean, are `true`. You can test boolean conversion with any value by computing `!!(value)`

Comment: Yes, I meant it will be equivalent if used as an `if` condition (boolean conversion implied). I should choose my wording more carefully.